# How to debug Office addins on Mac?

Tags: excel, reactjs, debugging, office-js

I am currently coding a taskpane add-in for Excel using React. The initial project was generated with the Yeoman generator and the React taskpane template.

Long story short, I miss-read the official documentation which lead me to believe that there was no way of actually debugging side-loaded add-ins on mac and a lot of frustration trying to debug my add-in.

---

**What I did to fix this:**

As RaymondLu kindly pointed out, the official documentation has a simple tutorial on how to get the Safari web inspector (i.e. developer console) to work with desktop add-ins on a mac. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac).

Comment: is this document helpful？ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac

Comment: @RaymondLu Yes, very helpful!